# Python script to use packages from Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am new to this and i apologise in advanced if this has been answered or is a stupid question, i just do not seem to be able to find the answer.

I am building scripts in Anaconda as i find the layout really helpful. I am trying to make a script that will be called by a bat file so i can schedule it.

The issue i find that when i write a python file and save it, it cannot import the same libraries as anaconda has.

My question is, is there a way that i can use the standard version of python on my computer but have it point at the packages that are installed for anaconda?

Again, very new to all of this and appreciate any direction that can be offered.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks. This does give me some insight. I have given a good read and taken in the info however i still have an issue that when i try clicking on a py file it cannot import from the anaconda package library. I tested by doing try import  pandas as pd except create file

Comment: What kind of workflow are you using? Your IDE should have a way of using a certain environment.

Comment: I use anaconda which has all of the packages other than that it's just the vanilla download of python from the website. I must be doing something wrong as I though of I just had the two installed they would share packages. The a was to just write up files in notepad and when it's called used the anaconda packages.